# stm32 nucleo 3.3V usage

Tags: stm32, 3.3v

This is probably an easy question. When using an STM32 Nucleo powered by a 5V power supply, can I use its 3V3 pin to supply 50mA? Or do I need to use for instance a 3V3 linear regulator attached to my 5V power supply.

Thank you.

Comment: Which board are you using?

Comment: The small arduino nano sized one. STMicroelectronics STM32 Nucleo-32 Development Board NUCLEO-G031K8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NUCLEO-G031K8 dev board uses a [LD39050PU33R](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00227527-1796864.pdf) regulator to provide 3.3V rail from other high voltage sources (USB 5V for example):

[image]

You can use the onboard 3.3V rail to power other devices but make sure not to cross 500mA limit of the regulator.

Here's  [the NUCLEO-G031K8 schematic](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/group1/05/c3/27/2a/6b/db/41/f1/MB1455-G031K8-C01_Schematic/files/MB1455-G031K8-C01_Schematic.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.MB1455-G031K8-C01_Schematic.pdf) for reference.